# How do we import stompjs in a browser? Or something like stompjs?

Tags: stompjs

I am trying to follow [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) `Spring` tutorial on how to use `websockets`.  I am using `webpack` to bundle my code and `babel` to convert it from `ES6`.  I am trying to pull in `sockjs` with a normal `import` statement.

```
import SockJS from 'sockjs'
```

But when `webpack` runs, I get missing module errors,

```
ERROR in ./~/stompjs/lib/stomp-node.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in /Users/name/Developer/cubs-stack-4/cubs-webapp/node_modules/stompjs/lib
 @ ./~/stompjs/lib/stomp-node.js 14:8-22

ERROR in ./~/websocket/package.json
Module parse failed: /Users/name/Developer/cubs-stack-4/cubs-webapp/node_modules/websocket/package.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "_args": [
|     [
|       "websocket@latest",
 @ ./~/websocket/lib/version.js 1:17-43
```

mainly because it is expecting to be run on `Node`.

I have 2 questions.

First, how do I get `stompjs` into my browser side code using an `import/require` statement?

Second, how come in the tutorial, they can drop `stompjs` in the `HEAD` and it doesn't blow up in the browser, but it does when I run the "same" code through `webpack`?

Answer (score 16):

It seems that stompjs library referenced in Spring's documentation is no longer developed, but there is fork that is maintained and with instructions on how to add it to your project available here: https://github.com/stomp-js/stomp-websocket

Here are the steps that I used to resolve this issue and to get things working in a React app with websockets on Spring backend:

```
# Add sockjs and stompjs dependencies
npm install sockjs-client --save
npm install @stomp/stompjs --save
```

Then import it into your app:

```
import SockJS from "sockjs-client"
import Stomp from "@stomp/stompjs"
```

You should now be able to use the frontend code from the Spring's documentation successfully.

Answer (score 15):

installing 'net' dependency solved my issue

```
npm i sockjs-client --save
npm i stompjs --save
npm i net
```

and import like this

```
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import * as Stomp from 'stompjs';
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to import `"sockjs-client": "^1.0.3"` in your package.json.

Then you can import it with

```
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client'
```

My `webpack.config.js` contains the library `'sockjs-client'`. 
Additionally I added the following conf, in order to ignore missing `net` module.

```
node: {
  net: 'empty',
  tls: 'empty',
  dns: 'empty'
}
```

Source: https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/665#issuecomment-113713020

Answer (score 0):

In ionic 6 Angular 12

1. Install

   npm i --save sockjs-client stompjs net
2. Then

   npm i --save-dev @types/sockjs-client @types.stompjs
3. Import using

`import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';`
`import * as Stomp from 'stompjs';`

4. To solve the issue with 'global' I had to add the following to index.html

   `<script type="application/javascript"> var global = window; </script>`

Answer (score -2):

To use stompjs in browser, just open file `your_path/node_modules/stompjs/index.js`, comment it like this:

```
var Stomp = require('./lib/stomp.js');
// var StompNode = require('./lib/stomp-node.js');

module.exports = Stomp.Stomp;
// module.exports.overTCP = StompNode.overTCP;
// module.exports.overWS = StompNode.overWS;
```